# User unexpectedly on 1 reputation

Tags: support, reputation, specific-user

I noticed [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218011/jason-clark?tab=profile) is on 1 reputation.

However there is no obvious reason why when they have some highly voted answers and only have given 50 rep away in bounties. Their graph doesnt show any drop to 1.

There is no message indicating that they are suspended and I test upvoted a question of theirs and their rep increased to 6 until I retracted it.

Has something gone awry here?

Comment: They lost 66 reputation seven days ago. Since it is not reflected in their rep activity, one would have to think that it was the result of the user downvoting 66 answers. Which happened the same day they got a few edits reverted.... It looks like a suspension for irregularities that's not properly reflected in their profile?

Comment: Maybe the suspension is finished but the job resetting the rep back is broken?

Comment: The rep graph shows the last value as 1101 so my guess would be a display error on the profile

Comment: @ivarni It's not only that. Suspended have their rep fixed at 1, as far as I know. And the OP in this question voted / unupvoted this user, and saw their reputation change. (And I've just replicated it, got their reputation to 11 and back to 1). Looks buggy to me.

Comment: Their meta account still shows 1,221 rep.

Comment: Maybe they posted 11 spam answers that got red flagged giving them enough -100 penalties to drop to 1

Comment: @rene it looks like [spam edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/521039/revisions). The rollback there says "Edit approval overridden by post owner or moderator". I think Martijn Pieters might have more information.

Comment: @TinyGiant ah, that is a good find and probably related, yes.

Comment: I count [7 out of a total of 9 suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218011/jason-clark?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) that were reverted spam edits. Also, at least [one rollback war](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33992175/revisions)

Comment: Reputation points are now 19.

Comment: Look at the reputation tab on him: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218011/jason-clark?tab=reputation, especially the sixth page!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The user had posted about a dozen spam answers advertising some tool or another, and earned a -100 penalty for each one when their behaviour was discovered about a week ago.

Comment: Something like that doesn't earn a user a suspension?

Comment: @yivi if posting unwanted content is a reason for suspension most new users would need to be suspended after their first post ...

Comment: @rene Unwanted content doesn't equal spam. That's the reason spam flags carry a 100 point penalty and off-topic deleted content, doesn't. I just thought that the accumulation of spam flags would carry a suspension.

Comment: Nothing automatic AFAIK @yivi. I think a suspension is in order if the behavior repeats after being warned / got penalized by the -100 rep. Not so on the first occurrence but I'm not a mod ...

Comment: @rene. I think they can consider themselves _warned_ from this point forward. :P

Comment: @yivi Usually it would get the account destroyed pronto, but this user seems to have other useful contributions besides spam, so it "just" earned him an answer ban and loss of reputation.

Comment: There seems to be something else going on, their meta user rep is 1221, or are punishments from the spam activities gotten harder lately? Or is it the answer ban, which drops the rep to 1 too? Bans have also been public, has that changed as well ..?

Comment: @Teemu meta reputation vs main reputation: always blame caching.

Comment: @Braiam Obviously my CTRL+F5 is stuck, since nothing changes when I press'em ..?

Comment: @Teemu caching doesn't only happens on client side.

Comment: @Teemu "earned a -100 penalty for **each one**"

Comment: @Braiam You caught me ...ofcourse, I coudn't even imagine there would have been more than 2 or 3 spam posts.

Comment: related: [-100 rep penalty effectiveness for spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301304/165773) at MSE

Comment: wow, A mod can give -100 penalty, how may points to I need to become a mod :)

Comment: one edit with that content would appear innocuous to me (I checked the one where the guy edited a post where the free version was mentionned already). But systematic edit with the same tool link, that is spam.

Comment: @DrDeo 3 normal user can do that too... if you can find any user with >100 rep post spam.

Comment: @user202729 fyi: it's 6 users required flagging as spam not 3...

Comment: Why does the rep loss not appear on their activity?

Comment: I think I am more concerned about the Suggested Edits "reviewers" approving these more than I am about the user making these edits. The review queue is filled with users who don't pay attention or just flat out don't care, assuming they aren't automating it. If you go through the H&I queue, you will immediately see those who should be review-banned for allowing that garbage in there from triage - I am not talking about edge cases, I am talking about just pure crap gets thrown in there.